# is that a ruby on rails strange behaviour with overwrite params? Or do I just dont aderstand ruby, again?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

pre annotation: I have a solution, I want to understand what happens here, and if this behaviour is intended

**edit** a try for a better readable shortcut:

if you have the following code in Rails Controller:

```
def get_page
    prepare_anythig params
    if is_it_monday?
         params=monday_default_paramms
    end
    finish_any_other_thing params
end
```

this works only on monday

Following functioning little controller function, not very intersting, I know

```
    class SvgTestController < SiteController
        def get_the_page
            require "base64"
            @main_width="auto"
            params[:ci]||=['default']
            puts  "? params:",params

            generate_drawing(params, false)
            render ...
        end
    end
```

the console shows me how expected:

```
    ? params:
    {"ci"=>"not default", "controller"=>"svg_test", "action"=>"get_the_page"}
```

Then I made a small (ok, erroneous or not valid as I now know - or think) change, I extended my `get_the_page` with 'get params via base64 encode json'

```
    class SvgTestController < SiteController
        def get_the_page
            require "base64"
            @main_width="auto"
            params[:ci]||=['default']
                    # add here
            puts  "? params:",params
            json=params[:json]
            puts "json?",json.inspect
            if json
                plain = Base64.decode64(json)
                puts "we are in here:", plain
                params=JSON.parse(plain).with_indifferent_access
                puts  "? params now:",params
            end
                     # end

            puts  "? params:",params

            generate_drawing(params, false)
            render ...
        end
    end
```

Solution working fine and the output like this:

```
   ? params:
   {"json"=>"eyJjaSI6eyIwMDAwMDAwMDAyMDQ4MDgiOnsic3J2IjoxfX19", "controller"=>"svg_test", "action"=>"get_the_page", "ci"=>["default"]}      
   json?
    "eyJjaSI6eyIwMDAwMDAwMDAyMDQ4MDgiOnsic3J2IjoxfX19"
    we are in here:
    {"ci":{"000000000204808":{"srv":1}}}
    ? params now:
    {"ci"=>{"000000000204808"=>{"srv"=>1}}}
    ? params:
    {"ci"=>{"000000000204808"=>{"srv"=>1}}}
```

later I got, working not with JSON-logic

```
 NoMethodError in SvgTestController#get_the_page
 undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

and my console shows me:

```
? params:
{"ci"=>"10.203.192.83", "controller"=>"svg_test", "action"=>"get_the_page"}
json?
nil
? params:
_(nothing to read here)_
```

So ruby overwrites my `params` (ok its a method, my fault)   even if not in `if ... end`?

Again I ask: Is this wanted? And if, how to prevent such errors without knowing all and all the time about whats behind `words` like `params`?

**edit**

My solution, *but not the answer to my question*

```
...
params_used=params
json=params[:json]
if json
  plain = Base64.decode64(json)
  params_used=JSON.parse(plain).with_indifferent_access
end
puts  "? params:",params_used
generate_drawing(params_used, false)
```

Comment: Maybe only me but I find your question hard to understand. If you have idea where the problem could happen, making it abstract would help quick solving.

Comment: "_(nothing to read here)_" -> as in really nothing, an empty string, nil, or as in the error occurs before it ever shows? +1 what @BillyChan said, btw. The question is hard to understand.

Comment: Could you provide full back trace?

Comment: @BillyChan: I see that, hard to read, but my brain is somehow mangled out after this search, I am happy that I got it that way

Answer (score 1):

I think the "error" is because you're actually *creating* a variable. Annotation of your code:

```
    def get_the_page
        require "base64"
        @main_width="auto"
        params[:ci]||=['default']        # params method
                                         # you modified @params, a mutable hash
                # add here
        puts  "? params:",params         # params method
        json=params[:json]               # params method
                                         # you accessed @params[:json]
        puts "json?",json.inspect
        if json
            plain = Base64.decode64(json)
            puts "we are in here:", plain
            params=JSON.parse(plain).with_indifferent_access  # params variable
            puts  "? params now:",params                      # params variable
        end
                 # end

        puts  "? params:",params                              # params variable

        generate_drawing(params, false)                       # params variable
        render ...
    end
```

What's happening, I'd wager, is that the Ruby interpreter picks up the fact that a *variable* named `params` continues to be used after if block, so proceeds to initialize it (to nil) immediately before your if block irrespective of whether the block is visited or not.

Comment: "is that the Ruby interpreter picks up the fact", this 'idea' is what made me ask the question, is that intended?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is, since doing so would allow to generate the op code once and subsequently use it any number of times thereafter.

Comment: this is realy hard for me to accept; if you (erronously) destroy or change an object in your code, there is no error. But you get killed for your mistake, if you erroonus code is not executed - thats a new hard world for me in debugging.

Comment: You're not destroying an object. Per the annotated version of your code I posted, the local variable doesn't exist until you allocate it. The initial version of the method is always calling the `params` method. The version with your modifications calls the `params` method until the interpreter runs into the (local) `params` variable that you create. If you need to access the `params` method from that point forward, you need to force the call by using `self.params`. `puts  "? self.params:", self.params` to see that in action.

Comment: I think I understand; the point is: I am used to struggle if I make a mistake, not if not ;-). What I mean is: `unless once_a_year make the mistake` works. ie. I get no warning, no error, no - nothing; all fine, until 'once a year' that is hard to test, and therefore I asked, if there is a method to prevent this?

Comment: Yes, there actually are two memo-technical methods: a) initialize variables within the scope that you plan to use them (assume that anything that isn't initialized is a method call), and b) avoid collisions between variable names and method names (particularly for property-related methods). Particularly so in a RoR context, since its docs implicitly suggest to use accessor methods (e.g. `params`) instead of direct access to properties (`@params`). Also, run your scripts using `ruby -w`; it'll show warnings when you do a number of potentially weird things.

Comment: upvote, because the first answer; now I have to find, where to tell my ruby mine the "-w", but this is OT ;-)

Comment: Try adding an alias to your profile: `alias ruby='ruby -w'`. For individual scripts, run `ruby -w` instead of the usual `ruby` to call them, or use `#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w` instead of the usual `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` or `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` or wherever it's located as their first line.

Comment: Another way is to set the `$VERBOSE` global to `true` in your scripts.